# How to select all occurrences of a specified word in a string and append another word to each of them?

Tags: programming, strings

When using `infix-RPN` package, we can use `\infixtoRPN` to convert infix expression to RPN expression. The output of the conversion can be retrieved by invoking `\RPN`.

`\infixtoRPN{cos(x)+sin(x)}`, for example, will yield `x cos x sin add` that is available in `\RPN`.

My question, how to insert `RadtoDeg` right after the `x`? So the final will be `x RadtoDeg cos x RadtoDeg sin add`.

The skeleton is given as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{infix-RPN}

\def\f(#1){cos(#1)+sin(#1)}

% #1 target word
% #2 inserted word
\def\appendtoRPNafter#1#2{%
    %implementation using \RPN goes here!
    %don't forget to return the result!
}
\begin{document}
    \infixtoRPN{\f(x)}%
    \appendtoRPNafter{x}{RadtoDeg}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Your MWE doesn't W)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{infix-RPN}

\def\f(#1){cos(#1)+sin(#1)}

    \infixtoRPN{\f(x)}%

\typeout{A: \RPN}

% #1 target word
% #2 inserted word
\def\appendtoRPNafter#1#2{%
\def\tmp##1 #1 ##2{##1\ifx\tmpb##2\else\space #1 #2 \expandafter\tmp\fi##2}%
\def\tmpb.{}%
\edef\RPN{\expandafter\tmp\RPN\tmpb. #1 \tmpb.}
}

    \appendtoRPNafter{x}{RadtoDeg}%

\typeout{B: \RPN}

\stop
```

Produces terminal output of

```
A:  x cos x sin add
B:  x RadtoDeg cos x RadtoDeg sin add
```